# How to get two or more maximum indexes values set to 1 from tf.softmax's output

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax

I want to get the maximum (2 or more) indexes set to 1 from the output of `tf.nn.softmax()`. 
given `tf.nn.softmax`'s  outputs as `[0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.8]` I want to get something like `[0,1,0,0,1]` since those indexes have the maximum numbers (in this case I chose just the maximum 2). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.nn.top_k`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k) that returns the highest values, together with their position, of the input vector.

```
probs = tf.nm.softmax(logits)
k = 2 # the first k=2 highest values
indices, values = tf.nn.top_k(probs, k=k)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tf.nn.softmax` forces everything to add up to `1.0` to make a valid probability distribution. If you want multiple values in the vector to be ones then you should use `tf.nn.sigmoid` instead.

If you want to retrieve the maximum numbers in the vector use `tf.nn.top_k`.